# Raspberry Pi and A9g module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, location, sms, microcontroller

How can I connect my a9g pudding module to my raspberry pi zero? I am planning to create a emergency alert system that will send gsm and gps location via sms. I am planning to use python and IOT platform in making this project

I am trying to search here but theres no similar project yet